# How to graceful shutdown Tomcat on Linux

Tags: linux, tomcat, shutdown, catalina

Is there a way to configure Tomcat in a way that when it stops (gracefully) it:

1. stop new requests
2. handle existing requests/connections

Comment: Did you try: `services tomcat stop`?

Comment: Does it wait to tomcat to finish the current requests or does it drop them?